# good unicorn + nginx + cap deploy howto?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, nginx, unicorn

Can anyone suggest a good good unicorn + nginx + cap deploy how to? 
I have searched high and low spend like 5 hours getting my deploy up and running with all kind or errors.

Comment: This reminds me. I planned to write my own a couple of days ago :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just yesterday I had to setup some Unicorns and nginx. I followed:

- [The article aa_memon already mentioned](http://ariejan.net/2011/09/14/lighting-fast-zero-downtime-deployments-with-git-capistrano-nginx-and-unicorn) and
- http://www.slideshare.net/mauricio.linhares/deploying-your-rails-application-to-a-clean-ubuntu-10

Also, here is my Unicorn config and init.d script: https://gist.github.com/2049606.

The deploy script I ended up using is almost identical to those mentioned in the links above. If you are using RVM, make sure you add something like:

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))  # Add RVM's lib directory to the load path.
require "rvm/capistrano"                                # Load RVM's capistrano plugin.
set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.3-p125@YOURGEMSET'           # Or whatever env you want it to run in.
```

A critical point is that you specify the PID files to be in the correct places (I mistyped that and it took me half an hour to find my mistake). Also make sure your user can write all necessary files.

Comment: great writeup although its for ubuntu I'm using centos. My unicorn path is for example totally different /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/unicorn_rails

Answer (score 4):

I like this one

http://ariejan.net/2011/09/14/lighting-fast-zero-downtime-deployments-with-git-capistrano-nginx-and-unicorn

Also github did a pretty good writeup on nginx and unicorn

https://github.com/blog/517-unicorn

Answer (score 0):

I guess one good answer to this is - https://coderwall.com/p/yz8cha. Its short & sweet and worked very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

This one is pretty comprehensive: http://isotope11.com/blog/deploying-a-rails-3-dot-2-plus-app-from-scratch-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

This looks very promising....

https://github.com/kalys/capistrano-nginx-unicorn